# How to identify assets a saved game actually uses in Cities: Skylines?

Tags: cities-skylines

#### When a saved game (from the Steam Workshop) lists thousands of assets (untrue), how do you determine which assets it actually *uses*?

You know *Cities: Skylines* supports user-generated assets in the workshop. You can "subscribe" to them, and they will appear in your game menus. I frequently see saved games on the Steam Workshop that load correctly *except for one key asset*, like a missing road or sewage plant. If you load the game, there will be a hole where a chunk of highway should be.

Like [this savegame](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=2663043608). Normally I go over to the Content Manager (in the opening screen), and see which assets the game uses, and subscribe to them. This doesn't tell me which asset is the road, so I have to take a few I don't care about. But then there's this game:

[image: link to fixed Steam game]

> "Custom assets/mods **used**: 1976"

*Bullpuckey!  The game loads fine, except for 1 Workshop road asset* (no, it's not Network Extensions, I have that). It's not actually using 1,976 assets (you would notice), and anyway, **this game is only a fixed version of [this other game](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=2661538369)**, that only "has" 79 assets (and I have those loaded since I'm playing that one).

[image: link to unfixed Steam game]

...so clearly, this number *has nothing to do with* the assets actually *used* in the save. This "monster list" is nothing more than a list of all the assets the author *happened to be subscribed to* at the time of the save. *If the author started a new game and built 1 plain road segment and saved, it too would "have" 1,976 assets despite having no assets at all.*

I want to load this save game, but I do not want to install 1,976 assets.

So here is my question: how do I "separate the wheat from the chaff", as it were?  How do I identify the 9 assets out of 1976 *actually used* by either game or the 1 asset I am missing?

Or alternatively, is there another way to resolve this? Can I tell the system to deal with the assets that are *actually* used an missing, by loading them "on the fly"?

Answer (score 2):

You can subscribe and enable the updated [Loading screen mod](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=2731207699) which will provide you with the list of all of the subscribed assets loaded into the game and the assets which are used in the current map.

To obtain this report, this report save options should be enabled in the Setting page of the Loading screen mod.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative option to the one posted by Elangesh - unfortunately depending on the save game to work even with missing mods - has been supplied by user Avanya on the [Steam forums](https://steamcommunity.com/app/255710/discussions/0/3148519255761348104/) (edited slightly for readability):

> You can use the output log (`player.log` on Mac and Linux) to find the mods used. To do this, you just load the save (which might not work since you're missing mods). Then you open the log and find a list of numbers. This is the Steam IDs for the mods used in the save. You then open a browser and add the ID number to the end of this URL:
> `https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=`
>
> That will take you to the mod's page.
>
> The list looks something like this in the log:
>
> ```
> The following mods were used when this asset was created: 
> UnlimitedMoney
> UnlimitedOilAndOre
> UnlockAll
> UltimateEyecandy
> 558661484
> 597981885
> 553501635
> 445589127
> 515489008
> 767233815
> 791221322
> 608517757
> ```